# unpack variadic template with scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using variadic templates, and I would like to find the good way to unpack my parameters

```
template <typename kernel_type, typename ...kernel_types>
class MetaKernel : public MyKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...> {
public:
    MetaKernel (
        unsigned int m,
        unsigned int n,
        const kernel_type& kernel_,
        const kernel_types&... kernels_
    ) :
        MyKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>(m, n)
    {
        Ks.set_max_size(sizeof...(kernel_types));
        Ks.set_size(sizeof...(kernel_types));
        // for each kernels_, add a MyObsKernel to Ks
        // Ks[sizeof...(kernel_types)].reset((new MyObsKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>(kernels_, prototypes_, m, n))...);
    }
private:
    array < scoped_ptr < MyObsKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...> > > Ks;
}
```

from the documentation ([http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter%5fpack)), I saw how to unpack like this:

```
int dummy[sizeof...(Ts)] = { (std::cout << args, 0)... };
```

but as I'm working on scoped_ptr table, I need to initialize it with a "reset". so my solution does not work. How can I unpack my parameters using scoped_ptr ?

thanks for your help,
Jerome

Comment: You class is incomplete above. Is `Ks` a member? What's the type? Is it `std::array`? If so, where is its size? Do you want to `reset()` each element of `Ks`?

Comment: Yes Ks is a member of the MetaKernel class. It's a dlib array of scoped_ptr and when initializing such an object, I need to reset the content. (I added the size initialization step)

Answer (score 2):

You may initialize `std::array` with an initializer-list. Following may help: https://ideone.com/PTwatb

```
MetaKernel (unsigned int m, unsigned int n, const kernel_type& kernel_, const kernel_types&... kernels_) :
    MyKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>(m, n),
    Ks({scoped_ptr<MyObsKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...> >(new MyObsKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>(kernels_, kernel_, m, n))...})
{
}
```

Comment: This looks indeed much simpler than my approach, but I supposed we should call method `reset()` to each element, which I have no idea what it means. But if all we need is initialization, then calling some `reset()` is a dumb thing to do. Assuming of course there is a such a constructor in `scoped_ptr` (which looks reasonable, but again I have no idea).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used this solution but as I'm using dlib and there was no builder using initializer_list for their array class. I had to add a builder using the initializer_list and what you gave me as solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, your question is incomplete. I understand that `Ks` is an `std::array` of size `N = sizeof...(kernel_types)`, and that you want to call `reset()` on each element. If so, here's a solution:

```
struct _do { template<typename... A> _do(A&&...) { } };

template <typename kernel_type, typename ...kernel_types>
class MetaKernel : public MyKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>
{
    using Base = MyKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>;
    using Obs  = MyObsKernel<kernel_type, kernel_types...>;
    static constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(kernel_types);

public:
    MetaKernel (
        unsigned int m,
        unsigned int n,
        const kernel_type& kernel_,
        const kernel_types&... kernels_
    ) : Base(m, n)
    {
        reset(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, N>(), m, n, kernels_...);
    }

private:
    template<size_t... I>
    void reset (
        std::integer_sequence<size_t, I...>,
        unsigned int m,
        unsigned int n,
        const kernel_types&... kernels_
    )
    {
        _do{Ks[I].reset(new Obs(kernels_, /*prototypes_,*/ m, n))...};
    }

    array <scoped_ptr <Obs>, N> Ks;
};
```

I am making use of the auxiliary object `_do` and C++14 features [`std::integer_sequence`, `std::make_index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). If this is not available, you can check `Range` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45334/39083), where `_do` is also explained.

You need a second function apart from the constructor in order to deduce index pack `I...` and use it to align with parameters `kernels_...` so that each parameter is used in exactly one call of `reset()` on one element of `Ks`.

If you have more such unpacking operations, it is better to have `I...` available in the entire class and use it directly. You will then need just a second `MetaKernelImpl` class instead of adding a second version for each function. This class will have an additional template parameter that is specialized for `std::integer_sequence<size_t, I...>` for some deduced pack `size_t... I`. Again, have a look at `Caller` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45334/39083) to see how this can be done.

Comment: I'm using c++11 and the example given following the link with Range is giving me that: erreur: expected nested-name-specifier before 'type'. Is it a synthax for c++11?

Comment: @user1595929 I have no idea what you are trying exactly. Try to share your code. For instance, in [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29d2306b001eb49) it is working just fine. Yes, it's C++11.

Comment: I have not been able to make the Range code working. I figured out using the initializer_list solution above.

Comment: @user1595929 Yes, this is the right thing to do, and much simpler. I couldn't figure out because I didn't know what `array` is, what `scoped_ptr` is, what `.reset()` means, and what you really wanted to do (initialize the array).